# How can I disable the multisite feature of WordPress 3.0?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I want to use the Google XML Sitemaps plugin and it says: "The plugin will not be active until you disable the multisite mode". I don't need a multisite mode.

Comment: And I even don't how my blog came into multiside mode. Default I guess?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/disabling-multisite-with-wp-30

http://www.bloggingjunkie.com/disable-multi-site-option-wordpress-30.html

Comment: It's always nice to say a few words about the problem instead of just pasting links.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake... I'll also add the summary from now onwards...

Comment: I only changed `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true)` in wp-config.php to `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false)` and the Google XML Sitemaps plugin is satisfied. Still don't know how this line came into my wp-config.php file

Answer (score 2):

You need to do three things (after backing up your database, of course).

1. Take out the multisite lines from wp-config.php. In my site, it was three lines referring to multiple domains and multiple sites.
2. Get rid of the multisite .htaccess. For this, you can either put back the old single-site .htaccess or empty it out. Either option will work.
3. Remove the multisite database tables:

   - wp_blogs
   - wp_blog_versions
   - wp_registration_log
   - wp_signups
   - wp_site
   - wp_sitemeta